# Conditional CSS Based on Being Viewed in Email or Internet Browser Client

Tags: css, conditional-statements

I want `CSS` to conditionally apply a style to a client dependent on whether the `HTML` is being viewed in an internet browser or an email client.

Is there a generic `CSS` condition statement to apply to all internet browsers?

Something like: `<!--[if gte mso 9]>` but `<!--[if chrome-ff-ie-opera-safari]>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make use of [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) here. Also check https://caniuse.com/css-featurequeries.

What you've shown is a) not CSS but an HTML *"conditional" comment* (from back-in-the-days, Internet Explorer 6-9 being the only browser to ever support this crude syntax; and even Internet Explorer stopped supporting it in version 10 and later (no other browser ever has)) and b) not what you should try. Instead work your way throught feature queries.

Declarations inside a feature query are conveniently ignored by clients not supporting `@supports`.